# how to get Background calls from IOS like google Authentication in android?

Tags: ios, iphone, verification, google-authentication

I want to do the verification like google Authentication in Android. First How my android app do like below

The token was issued by server.
The token was sent to a device that was being operated by the person identified.
The token was obtained by the Android app identified by the Client ID.

I found some Documents related to This but I don't know how to achieve this kind of security authentication in IOS. is their any way to do with out using google authentication in ios. Is there somethings similar for iOS from Apple, where I can get a ID token signed by Apple when Apple will observe that the iOS app and the client?

I found some Links on Google but no use Please any body guide me how to achieve This.

Comment: what exactly want to do using Google Integration

Comment: @JoyalClifford Thanks for the replay i am asking for similar one like google authentication for generating token in ios.

Comment: Just Google it oauth 2.0